# PHP and tables?

Tags: php, mysql

Hello Im new in PHP and have some troubles.

I have a mysql table called Services. I want to show some columns of that table in a html table. The problem is that I dont how to pass the entities as column and the atributes as rows. Please help me!!

Answer (score 1):

For example, I have a table `cars` with fields in select. Here is how you do it. Assume `$conn` is my mysql connection.

```
<?php
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>id</th>';
echo '<th>make</th>';
echo '<th>model</th>';
echo '<th>vin</th>';
echo '</tr>';
$result = mysql_query($conn, 'SELECT id, make, model, vin FROM cars');
while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) != NULL) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['make'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['model'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['vin'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
mysql_free_result($result);
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You were close. I made a few changes. Does this work as expected?

```
<?php
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>id</th>';
echo '<th>make</th>';
echo '<th>model</th>';
echo '<th>vin</th>';
echo '</tr>';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT id, make, model, vin FROM cars');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['make'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['model'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['vin'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
mysqli_free_result($result);
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: Quick question, why did you use mysqli_free_result? Was that in place of mysqli_close or is that so you free memory for the next query? Thanks

Comment: The person who post this question had it in his original sample code. You don't have to explicitly close your DB connection as PHP accomplishes this for you when your script ceases execution; however, you might was to use mysqli_free_result() to free up resources so you can execute the next query if you're dealing with a lot of data.